# Regex-ing Words, Numbers, And Quotations from a string in Java

Tags: java, regex, string, words

I have a quick question about Regex in Java (though other languages are probably similar).

What I'm trying to do is to transform a String like this:

```
 How are you "Doing well" How well 10 "That's great"

//# I want the Regex in Java to match out all of the words, numbers, 
//# and things inside quotation marks. Ideally, I'd get something like this 

How
Are
You
"Doing Well"
How 
Well
10
"That's Great!"
```

The Regex I'm trying to use is the following:

```
String RegexPattern =   "[^"+           //  START_OR: start of line OR" 
                        "\\s" +         //  empty space OR
                        "(\\s*?<=\")]" + // ENDOR: preceeded by 0 or more spaces and a quotation mark 
                        "(\\w+)" +      // the actual word or number
                        "[\\s" +        // START_OR: followed by a space OR
                        "(?=\")" +      // followed by a quotation mark OR
                        "$]";           // ENDOF:  end of line
```

This Won't work for me, though; even for much simpler strings! I've spent a lot of time looking for similar problems on here. If I didn't need the quotations, I could just use a split; eventually, though, this pattern will get much more complicated, so I will need to use the Regex (this is just the first iteration).

I'd appreciate any help; thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `[ ]` means what you think it means.  Inside square brackets, `^` is actually a negation operator for the character class.  You should practice with smaller regexes before embarking on this task.  The pattern you're looking for is more like:

```
    \s*([^"\s]+|"[^"]*")
```

You can see this in action here: http://rubular.com/r/enq7eXg9Zm.

If you don't want symbols in words, then it's probably best to use a second regex that removes them, e.g.

```
    \W
```

Comment: I'll try to explain the first regex.  `\s*` matches zero or more whitespace characters.  `( ... | ... )` is an alternation operator: match one, and if not possible, then match the other.  The first half of that alternation, `[^"\s]+`, matches a string of non-double-quote, non-whitespace characters--in other words, a "normal" word.  The second half of that alternation, `"[^"]*"` (again, only triggering if the first half fails), matches a double-quote, then a string of non-double-quote characters, then another double-quote.

Comment: ah, gotcha! you are right, I didn't understand the square brackets. Sorry about That!

Comment: Well, I was definitely wrong about the brackets, but I'm not sure ruby's entirely consistent with Java (which is fine though!) Check this link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html . The Bracket are used in place of the "|" you use (for OR). Nothing big, just language syntax differences.

Comment: I see why you might think `[ ... ]` is an OR operator, but there is a big difference: it is merely an OR operator for _single characters_. That is, no matter what you put between `[` and `]`, the expression can only match a single character! This is unlike the alternation operator, `|`, which is an OR operator for _expressions_. Another way of saying this is this. It is true that `[abcd1234]` is equivalent to `(a|b|c|d|1|2|3|4)`. However, you cannot convert `(hi|hello|howdy)` to an expression in terms of `[ ... ]`!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in multiple steps (code in python but the logic and the pattern should be the same)

1 - Get all the strings within double quotes:

```
r = re.findall(r'\"([^"]*)\"','How are you "Doing well" How well 10 "That\'s great"')
```

Result: `['Doing well', "That's great"]`

2 - Remove those strings from the text:

```
r = re.sub(r'\"([^"]*)\"', "", 'How are you "Doing well" How well 10 "That\'s great"')
```

Result: `'How are you  How well 10 '`

3 - Now you can do your split plus the ones in double quotes from step 1.

definitively not a good/clean solution but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. 
(\"[^\"]+\")|([^\s]+)